# why the documentation in wp-api backbone js client doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, backbone.js

```
    var post = new wp.api.models.Post( { id: 1 } );
post.fetch();

// Get a collection of the post's categories (returns a promise)
// Uses _embedded data if available, in which case promise resolves immediately.
post.getCategories().done( function( postCategories ) {
// ... do something with the categories.
// The new post has an single Category: Uncategorized
console.log( postCategories[0].name );
// response -> "Uncategorized"
} );
```

I try this out from wordpress https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/ and i didn't get any log ??

It works for me instead

```
var post = new wp.api.models.Post( { id: 1 } );    
post.fetch({
    success: function(model, response, options){

    console.log(model.get('slug');

    },
    error: function(model, response, options){
    // alert('Fetch error');
    }
    });
```

Comment: The documentation you quoted isn't meant to be taken like one big sequential snippet, **it's multiple unrelated examples** dumped into one pre-formatted section.

Comment: merci beaocoup !!